# Equivalent of M2E's Maven -> Update Project for Gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When using Maven/M2E within eclipse, I can right click a project and choose Maven -> Update Project to synchronize my classpath, source folders etc. with the settings I have in my POM file.

When using gradle, is my only option to regenerate my eclipse project files using the Eclipse Plugin?  Is there a better way to achieve the same functionality?

-JP

Comment: Please don't use the sts tag. Use one of the unambiguous tags listed at [the "Ambiguous tag: sts" post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78923/148310).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Eclipse Gradle tooling, there is an equivalent option to synchronize the project. If you use the file generation approach, you need to regenerate files with `gradle eclipse`.